# How to get the autocomplete list based on array of cities using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to get the autocomplete values based on some city using google place API in Javascript. But as per my code its not working as expected.

Here I have some cities in array like `city=['Bhubaneswar','Balesore','abcd']` and When user will type to get the place the matching should be belongs to these cities only. I am explaining my code below.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MAP_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript" async defer></script> 
function initMap() {
      var city=['Bhubaneswar','Balesore','abcd'];
      var input = document.getElementById('pick_addr');
      var options = {
               types: ['(cities)'],
               componentRestrictions: {country: "IN"}
      };
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
}
```

As per my code its coming for one country but I need only per city based.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want the autocomplete to only return the cities in your array? Or any result within the area of these cities?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: Yes I need any area belongs to that cities present inside that array.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to restrict Places Autocomplete results to specific cities/localities. As a workaround for now, you can bias the autocomplete results to favor an approximate location or area as stated in this **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area)**.

There is also an existing feature request to filter using
route, locality, administrative_area, postal_code and country in the Places API autocomplete. I'd recommend you "star" it to receive updates.
            https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067

Hope this helps!