# Restricting search in a specific city on Google Maps Places Autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps

I am building an app to basically search places such as burger kings but in a specific city.

I tried to use google maps autocomplete API.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=burgerking&key=MY_API_KEY&components=country:uk
```

As you can see, I can restrict the search in specific countries but not in cities.
I do not want to give a location parameter of center of the city and give a search radius since every city has different sizes. I want this app to work in all UK cities

Is there any way to search it within a city using this API.

Comment: Restrict the search with each city bounds.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Do you know any way to get city bounds? I suppose they should be on longitude and longitude

Comment: The API doesn't provide it. You might find external data sources for that. But that's the way it is: radius or bounds are the only ways to go.

Comment: see my answer here, hope it helps: stackoverflow.com/a/62294304/4324194

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897475/how-to-get-the-autocomplete-list-based-on-array-of-cities-using-javascript/56948095#56948095), it is not currently possible to restrict Places Autocomplete results to specific cities/localities.

Using the [Places Autocomplete web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete), you will need to define the `location` and `radius` parameter to restrict the results to that region by setting "strictbounds" to true.

Using the [JavaScript Autocomplete Widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), you can check out some options in this **[guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area)** to set biases and search-area boundaries. You can use the **Strict Bounds** option to restrict the search to the area within the current viewport or the bounds that are explicitly set. Here's a working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/aaarangco05/s62e5Lgt/6/) that you can check which initially sets the bounds to St. Helens.

You can get the `"bounds"` of a city by making a [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results) request.

There is also an existing feature request to allow filter using
route, locality, administrative_area, postal_code and country in the Places API autocomplete. I'd recommend you "star" it to receive updates.
            https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067

Hope this helps!